# django and celery beat scheduler no database entries

Tags: mysql, django, celery, celerybeat

my problem is that the beat scheduler doesn't store entries in the table 'tasks' and 'workers'. i use django and celery. in my database (MySQL) i have added a periodic tast "Estimate Region" with Interval 120 seconds.

this is how i start my worker:

```
`python manage.py celery worker -n worker.node1 -B --loglevel=info &`
```

after i started the worker i can see in the terminal that the worker works and the scheduler picks out the periodic task from the database and operates it.

how my task is defined:

```
@celery.task(name='fv.tasks.estimateRegion',
             ignore_result=True,
             max_retries=3)
def estimateRegion(region):
```

terminal shows this:

```
WARNING ModelEntry: Estimate Region fv.tasks.estimateRegion(*['ASIA'], **{}) {<freq: 2.00 minutes>}
[2013-05-23 10:48:19,166: WARNING/MainProcess] <ModelEntry: Estimate Region fv.tasks.estimateRegion(*['ASIA'], **{}) {<freq: 2.00 minutes>}>
INFO Calculating estimators for exchange:Bombay Stock Exchange
```

the task "estimate region" returns me a results.csv file, so i can see that the worker and the beat scheduler works. But after that i have no database entries in "tasks" or "workers" in my django admin panel.

Here are my celery settings in settings.py

`   CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = True
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
    CELERY_IMPORTS = ('fv.tasks')
    CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = True

```
# amqp settings
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://fv:password@localhost'
#BROKER_URL = 'amqp://fv:password@192.168.99.31'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 18000
CELERY_ROUTES = (fv.routers.TaskRouter(), )
_estimatorExchange = Exchange('estimator')
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('celery', Exchange('celery'), routing_key='celery'),
    Queue('estimator', _estimatorExchange, routing_key='estimator'),
)

# beat scheduler settings
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"

# development settings
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = False
CELERY_DEFAULT_DELIVERY_MODE = 'transient'`
```

i hope anyone can help me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you started celerycam?

```
python manage.py celerycam
```

It will take a snapshot (every 1 second by default) of the current state of tasks.

You can read more about it in the [celery documentation](https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/release21-maint/userguide/monitoring.html#starting-the-monitor)

Comment: Great, first i thought the -B option also enables the celerycam. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem! If this is the solution to your issue then please mark it as the accepted answer to help others who have the same problem in the future.